# screen flickering, turning off, 18.10 Intel

Tags: 18.04, display, intel, 18.10, monitor

I recently moved my work computer home and hooked it to new monitors. One monitor works perfectly, the other (an AOC monitor connected via displayport) flickers and tears occasionally, and then will put itself to sleep and I have to disconnect/reconnect it to the computer to wake it up.

I never had this problem previously with other Dell monitors at the office. I had the problem with 18.04 so tried updating to 18.10 and the problem persists. I've also tried changing the refresh rate to no avail.

This is the output of `xrandr`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
HDMI-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   1920x1080     63.69*+  60.00    60.00    50.00    59.94    24.00    23.98  
   1920x1080i    60.00    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1280x720      60.00    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00    50.00  
   720x576i      50.00    50.00  
   720x480       60.00    60.00    59.94    59.94    59.94  
   720x480i      60.00    60.00    59.94    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 509mm x 286mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00    50.00    50.00  
   720x480       60.00    60.00    59.94    59.94    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  

HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

And calling `lspci | grep VGA` gives:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
```

I'm stumped. Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: If you just 'updated' to 18.10, release-upgrade to 19.04 asap as 18.10 reached EOL yesterday, and is thus off-topic here (or restore a 18.04 LTS backup).

Comment: damn, hard to keep up! okay i'll upgrade again and see if the problem persists. thnx